# Why can't my redirected webflow find my bean and use it

Tags: jsf-2, spring-webflow

I'm using JSF2.0 with Spring Webflow 2.3 .

I've been trying to get information on what link has been clicked in my page and how many times it has been clicked. Now it works when I stay in the flow and just go to another flow but when I redirect and then return it just resets my bean. I feel like i am missing something but i don't know what.

I've tried about everything my little head can think off and i've tried researching but my guess is my search parameters aren't correct cause all I find doesn't help.

This is my backing bean:

```
@SessionScoped
public class CountBean implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 7498596369206276696L;
private static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(CountBean.class);
private String link;
private Map<String,Integer> counter;



public CountBean(){
    if(counter == null || counter.isEmpty()){
        counter = new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>();
    }
    link = null;
}



public void countTheCount(){
    if(link != null){
    int value;
    if(counter.containsKey(link)){
        value = counter.get(link);
        value++;
        counter.put(link, value);
    } else {
        value = 1;
        counter.put(link, value);
    }
    logger.debug("Click: "+link+" , times: "+value);
    }
}

public String getLink() {
    return link;
}

public void setLink(String link) {
    this.link = link;
}


}
```

And this is my flow:

```
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">

<var name="testBean" class="be.admb.myadmbresearch.beans.TestBean" />
<var name="countBean" class="be.admb.myadmbresearch.beans.CountBean" />


<view-state id="test-view" model="testBean">
    <transition on="logTest">
        <evaluate expression="testBean.testWarning()" />
        <evaluate expression="countBean.countTheCount()" />
    </transition>
    <transition on="gotoxy" to="sample-view">
        <evaluate expression="countBean.countTheCount()" />
    </transition>
    <transition on="gotoab" to="sample-redirect-view">
        <evaluate expression="countBean.countTheCount()" />
    </transition>
    <transition on="gotogoogle" to="gotoGoogle-view">
        <evaluate expression="countBean.countTheCount()" />
    </transition>
</view-state>
<view-state id="sample-redirect-view" view="externalRedirect:contextRelative:sample.html" />
<view-state id="gotoGoogle-view" view="externalRedirect:http://www.google.be" />
<view-state id="sample-view">
    <transition on="keerdekewere" to="test-view">
        <evaluate expression="countBean.countTheCount()"/>
    </transition>
</view-state>
```

Edit: Forgot to add the redirected sample-flow:

```
<var name="countBean" class="be.admb.myadmbresearch.beans.CountBean" />
<view-state id="sample-view" >
    <transition on="keerdekewere" to="test-view">
        <evaluate expression="countBean.countTheCount()"/>
    </transition>
</view-state>

<view-state id="test-view" view="externalRedirect:contextRelative:test.html" />
```

If anyone could help me or even think of anything i would be very gratefull.

Thanks in advanced.

Rafael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it by using a HttpSession directly setting the counter eachtime i run countTheCount(), now this seems to work but i don't know if it is the right solution, some feedback would be nice.

This is what i got:

```
public CountBean(){
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
    if(session != null){
        counter = (Map<String, Integer>) session.getAttribute("counter");
    if(counter == null || counter.isEmpty()){
        counter = new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>();
        session.setAttribute("counter", counter);
    }
    }
    link = null;
}

public void countTheCount(){
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
    if(link != null){
    int value;
    if(counter.containsKey(link)){
        value = counter.get(link);
        value++;
        counter.put(link, value);
        session.setAttribute("counter", counter);
    } else {
        value = 1;
        counter.put(link, value);
        session.setAttribute("counter", counter);
    }
    logger.debug("Click: "+link+" , times: "+value);
    }
}
```